# GstAppSink: Sharing between two pipelines

Tags: video-streaming, h.264, gstreamer-1.0, jetson-xavier, rtsp-server

We're trying to use appsink from one pipeline, which reads camera image data from appsrc using aravis library in gst-rtsp-server as a buffer provider for need-data signal.

The camera is acquiring image data in **BayerRG8** pixel format, we convert it using `bayer2rgb` then link to `videoconvert` and send result to `appsink`.

We used source code of arv-viewer tool to acquire frames from camera and appsrc example of gst-rtsp-server.

**Question:**
Can we use appsink for rtsp server's appsrc in need-data callback, and which pipeline launch to use in media factory for our appsink?

The appsink is shared between 2 services:
 one dealing with camera and another dealing with server?

Comment: I don't use GStreamer but if you can get the result of appsink as H.264 bytes (in Array) then maybe just have your app do a connection to the RTSP server and then manually send (to server) the array that you receive from appsink. This should avoid needing 2 GStreamer pipelines.

Comment: not sure about `appsink` but I have successfully implemented this using `shmsink` and `shmsrc`